# Duplicate div with script/style tags inside using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html code:

```
<table><tbody><tr><td>
      <div id="div_1">
          <style>...</style>
          <div><label> 1 </label></div>
          <div><input type="text" name="text_1"/></div>
          <script>$("#text_1").mask("99/99/9999");</script>   
          <div><label><a onclick="javascript:insert_div()"> </a></label></div>  
          ...    
      </div>                    
      ...                
      <div id="div_20">
           <style>...</style>
           <div><label> 1 </label></div>
           <div><input type="text" name="text_20"/></div>
           <script>$("#text_20").mask("99/99/9999");</script>   
           <div><label><a onclick="javascript:insert_div()"> </a></label></div>  
           ...    
      </div>
</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

That generates this (from 1 to 20, actually):

[image]

What I need is to insert a whole new div when the user presses the arrow button. It should copy the div with scripts and styles and insert after them with a new number (e.g. 21, then 22, etc.).

Comment: So where's the problem?

Comment: I don't know to to implement the "insert_div" function that is going to do this.

Comment: Do not do it this way. Use jQuery to register the events and connect the `mask` to the copy. Avoid using *attribute-based* event handlers if you have jQuery.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie You know that jQuery is just a JS framework, right? Everything it can do can be easily done in plain JS.

Comment: @Shomz: It is not easier or shorter to do multiple event registration in raw Javascript (especially with attribute-based handlers). You do know that Jquery is designed to simplify code don't you? ;)

Comment: @carla You need to write a function that will build the next row and append it to the container. Also, you don't need to define style/add scripts for each row. There is *so much* that needs to be improved here.

Comment: I must now agree with @Shomz at last. You need to define the actual problem you are trying to solve instead, as the way you are approaching it now is "more than a bit odd" :) What is your server technology? PHP? ASP/MVC?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Depends on how much you care about performance. I do, I have to. Even if it involves writiting a few more lines of code.

Comment: @Shomz: I tend to ignore anyone that feels user input tasks are somehow *too fast* for their browser without raw JS. Unless you are typing 50,000 characters or 50,000 clicks per second, that argument is pointless when compared against the benefits of writing shorter, simpler, maintainable code :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Sorry, but, what do you mean by "register the events and connect the mask to the copy", I've just started using JS/Jquery. And Shomz I know there are very bad practices in use here, but that is an old code I'd rather not to change much; and writing this function that appends a row to the container is exactly what I don't know how to do. (PS: I use PHP)

Comment: @carla: You have actually shown very little code, so a complete re-write is not excessive to clean things up. I will mock up an example (if no one gets there first with a good example).

Comment: As you will likely post back the values in this form, the pattern of the naming of the inputs will depend on your server technology. Are you using PHP or ASP/MVC?

Comment: @carla Rewriting this would be very beneficial. Sometimes you just need to sit and bite the bullet. Carrying over a lot of badly written code might get you in trouble one day when it piles up. I strongly suggest you hire someone to take care of all that (if you can't do it yourself, as you say). Stack Overflow is for helping with specific issues, not writing everything from scratch.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I use PHP as I said in the edit of my last comment. Shomz, that is just the tip of the iceberg , whether I keep implementing new features or I fix the ancient stuff.(http://xkcd.com/1319/)

Comment: Haha, yeah, the standard dev flow... Sadly, you know you'll have to do both eventually.

Comment: Most client-side web code, more than a few years old, will be best suited for the trash compactor. Things keep progressing rapidly (hence the example below looks nothing like the original, but includes a load of modern techniques).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is purely an instructional example of an alternate way of doing this task. It is intentionally wordy to provide ideas.

**Suggestion: Avoid attribute-based event handlers when using jQuery:**

To clarify my first comment. If you use `onclick=javascript` handlers, you are placing the registration of the event in the HTML, separate to the actual handler in the script. The "jQuery way" is to apply the handler function to a selection of elements, using methods like `.click()` and the rather useful `.on()` which I use below. This makes maintaining pages easier as you are not hunting through the HTML for JavaScript snippets. jQuery event handlers also support having more than one handler, for the same event, attached to an element *which you simply cannot do with `onclick=`*.

**Concepts shown:**

- Use a global counter for the next id number and simply increment it after each use
- Use a *delegated event handler* to process the "add" clicks as the elements are added dynamically (so do not exist until later).
- Use a template stored in a dummy `<script>` block to hold your template HTML (this `text/template` type is unknown so is ignored by all browsers. It also makes maintenance a breeze.
- Replace placeholder markers in the template with the new id information
- Convert the HTML to DOM elements using `$(html)`
- Find descendants in the new row to add things like `mask`.
- Append the new row

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Lu0q0na2/2/

```
// Declare a global counter for our new IDs
id = 2;

// Listen for click events at a non-changing ancestor element (delegated event handler)
$(document).on('click', '.addnew', function(e){

    // get the HTML of the template from the dummy script block
    var template = $('#template').html();

    // Change the template names etc based on the new id
    template = template.replace('{name}', 'name' + id).replace('{id}', id);

    // Increase next id to use
    id++;

    // Convert the HTML into a DOM tree (so we can search it easily)
    var $template= $(template);

    // Apply the mask to the newly added input - alter this to suit
    $template.find('input').mask("99/99/9999");

    // Append the new row
    $('table').append($template);

    // stop the link from moving to page top
    return false;
});
```

*I will be happy to explain any part of this if you have questions. I realise it may be a bit of a shock compared to the existing way of doing it you have :)*

Comment: It's indeed a beautifuly clean example. Even if is isn't helping me now thank you for share.

Comment: @carla: If you provide your entire page, and styling, I can show you that these techniques will indeed solve your immediate problem :)

Comment: "There are more things in heaven and earth, @TrueBlueAussie, than are dreamt of in your philosophy". My application in PHP has lots and lots of functions that generate the  HTML. To generate the mask, for example, a function is called and you pass the id of the element, almost everything is a function  that is used in other places. I can't just change all the things. However, I very much appreciate your generous offer. I will work on the things you all have said and then I'll come back.

Answer (score 1):

I give you the basic idea: the rest if left as an exercise as teachers say:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var last_inserted = 0;

 function insert_div(){
     $d = $("#div_" + last_inserted).clone();
     $d.attr('id', 'div_' + last_inserted++);
     $("table").append($d);
 }
</script>
```

And something else: `<a onclick="javascript:insert_div()">` is probably not correct (untested).

Either: `<a onclick="insert_div()">` or `<a href="javascript:insert_div()">`

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that she will also need a counter of some kind (for those IDs and input names, but even that could be rewritten into classes and array input names).

Comment: That *last inserted id* code almost deserves a down-vote for massive inefficiency alone :)

Comment: Yup, what @TrueBlueAussie said. Counting elements is easy, so is keeping track of inserted items.

Comment: @M.Page Thank you for your help. Altough, my table has borders, and when I executed this code the div was appended after the bottom border...=/